# CUDA float precision not matching CPU implementation

Tags: cuda, precision

I am using CUDA 5.5 compute 3.5 on GTX 1080Ti and want to compute this formula:

y = a * a * b / 64 + c * c

Suppose I have these parameters:

```
a = 5876
b = 0.4474222958088
c = 664
```

I am computing this both via GPU and on the CPU and they give me different inexact answers:

```
h_data[0]  = 6.822759375000e+05,
h_ref[0]   = 6.822760000000e+05,
difference = -6.250000000000e-02
```

h_data is the CUDA answer, h_ref is the CPU answer. When I plug these into my calculator the GPU answer is closer to the exact answer, and I suspect this has to do with floating point precision. My question now is, how can I get the CUDA solution to match the precision/roundoff of CPU version? If I offset the `a` parameter by +/-1 the solutions match, but if I offset say the `c` parameter I still get a difference of 1/16

Here's the working code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

__global__ void test_func(float a, float b, int c, int nz, float * __restrict__ d_out)
{
  float *fdes_out = d_out + blockIdx.x * nz;
  float roffout2 = a * a / 64.f;
  //float tmp = fma(roffout2,vel,index*index);
  for (int tid = threadIdx.x; tid < nz; tid += blockDim.x) {
    fdes_out[tid] = roffout2 * b + c * c;
  }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
  // parameters
  float a = 5876.0f, b = 0.4474222958088f;
  int c = 664; 

  int nz = 1;
  float *d_data, *h_data, *h_ref;
  h_data = (float*)malloc(nz*sizeof(float));
  h_ref  = (float*)malloc(nz*sizeof(float));
  
  // CUDA
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, sizeof(float)*nz); 
  dim3 nb(1,1,1); dim3 nt(64,1,1);
  test_func <<<nb,nt>>> (a,b,c,nz,d_data);
  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, sizeof(float)*nz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  
  // Reference
  float roffout2 = a * a / 64.f;
  h_ref[0] = roffout2*b + c*c;
  
  // Compare
  printf("h_data[0]  = %1.12e,\nh_ref[0]   = %1.12e,\ndifference = %1.12e\n",
    h_data[0],h_ref[0],h_data[0]-h_ref[0]);

  // Free
  free(h_data); free(h_ref);
  cudaFree(d_data);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling only with the`-O3` flag.

Comment: Also note that the difference is just 1 LSB for a float. I tested this in MATLAB, and the operation with floats gives me `y_float=682276` and with doubles `y_double=682275.966221463`. Note that the difference to this "true" result is less than the LSB for that number in float, meaning both are *almost equally* correct. Note that the GPU one is slightly closer to the double precission answer than the CPU one, reinforcing @njuffa 's guess

Comment: Yes, according to my testing, the difference goes away when the code is compiled with `-fmad=false`.  And OP has already stated " the GPU answer is closer to the exact answer"  @njuffa if you want to provide an answer I would upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This small numerical difference of one single-precision [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) occurs because the CUDA compiler applies FMA-merging by default, whereas the host compiler does not do that. FMA-merging can be turned off by adding the command line flag `-fmad=false` to the invocation of the CUDA compiler driver `nvcc`.

FMA-merging is a compiler optimization in which an FMUL and a dependent FADD are transformed into a single [fused multiply-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply%E2%80%93add), or FMA, instruction. An FMA instruction computes `a*b+c` such that the full unrounded product `a*b` enters into the addition with `c` before a final rounding is applied to produce the final result.

Usually, this has performance advantages, since a single FMA instruction is executed instead of two instructions FMUL, FADD, and all the instructions have similar latency. Usually, this also has accuracy advantages as the use of FMA eliminates one rounding step and guards against [subtractive cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) when `a*c` and `c` have opposite signs.

In this case, as noted by OP, the GPU result computed with FMA is slightly more accurate than the host result computed without FMA. Using a higher precision reference, I find that the relative error in the GPU result is -4.21e-8, while the relative error in the host result is 4.95e-8.